# Submitting ajax form with jQuery, and receiving another form to submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I am creating an application which will add a DOM object as a child to another DOM object, and this child can then have child objects. I am using form submission and validation, as shown below. The issue is that when I submit and receive an AJAX response, I add the new form to the DOM, and when that is submitted it bypasses the initializeSubmit function and loads a new page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#wpbody-content form').each(initializeSubmit);
});

function initializeSubmit () {
    var $ = jQuery,
        $form = $(this),
        options = {
            submitHandler: function() {
                var postdata = {},
                    $inputs = $form.find('input, textarea'),
                    edit_fields = {};
                $inputs.each( function () {
                    // gather postdata
                });
                $.ajax( {
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType : 'html',
                    url : ajaxurl,
                    cache : false,
                    data : postdata,
                    success : function ( response ) {
                            $container = $form.parent();
                            $container.after(response);
                            $newform = $(response).find('form');
                            $newform.each(initializeSubmit);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    $form.validate(options);
};
```

I've also tried to use apply instead of each within the success function:

```
initializeSubmit.apply($newform);
```

A console log shows the appropriate form within a jQuery array for $newform. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `$(response).find('form')` creates a different DOM transform of `response` from the one that was inserted with `$container.after(response);`.

You need to ensure that `.find('form')` acts on the DOM node that was actually inserted.

Try:

```
success : function ( response ) {
    var $response = $(response);
    $form.parent().after($response);
    $response.find('form').each(initializeSubmit);
}
```

Comment: The forms present on the webpage at loading work perfectly. It is when forms are loaded dynamically that $('form').each(initializeSubmit) isn't working properly.

Comment: OK, my bad. I have just done a 100% edit of my answer. See if it makes any more sense.

Comment: Good call! Working like a charm now.